# What benefits does Flask-Security provide when integrated into a project?

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-admin, flask-security

I am working on a Flask site I inherited from the last person to hold my position. It is a fairly large project with a lot of code, so any fundamental changes I want to make involve a lot of refactoring and rewriting code. With this being said, are there many tangible benefits in trying to integrate Flask-Security this late in the game? The site seems to have a pretty solid authentication system to me. It already uses Flask-Login, Flask-Admin, Flask-Mail, and a bunch of the other packages included in Flask-Security, so it seems like I'm deciding on whether a small change in functionality is worth all the work of implementing it.

This might not be the right place for it, but I am hoping to hear from people who have used Flask-Security and have a good idea of why it would be beneficial to add it rather than using the packages separately. It probably won't be a high-traffic site, but I don't want to create security risks by making the wrong choice.

Thanks!